# dead.letter issue on Linux?

Tags: mailx

I am sending mail to a list of users, using the `mailx` utility:

```
mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $FILE
```

It is working fine with valid emails, but I am getting a `dead.letter` issue when I try to send mail like `adffadf`, i.e., the string is not a valid email,

I want this `dead.letter` to not be occurring even for users having anything for email ID, e.g., `abc@gmail.com, abc@def.cc, adffdfs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for my mailx says a lot of things about set nosave and so on, but they don't seem to work. The only way to stop your dead.letter file growing I have found is to replace it by a link to the special file /dev/null.

```
rm ~/dead.letter

ln -s /dev/null ~/dead.letter
```

Answer (score 5):

The [man page for mailx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx) says that the `DEAD` environment variable can be used to override the `dead.letter` file. Set it to `/dev/null` and you should get no more dead letters

```
export DEAD=/dev/null    # sh, bash, ksh, ...
setenv DEAD /dev/null    # csh, tcsh
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i just want to skip deat.latter error, even email id is not correct, is there any way to do so?

Comment: i have set environmenet variable export DEAD=/dev/null but i am still getting dead.latter file

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore please [update your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/220164/edit) to indicate the OS that you're running on, and the version of `mailx`. Does the man page for your version of `mailx` offer the `DEAD` environment variable?

Comment: i got below info but i don't know how to set **save**  environment variable
save -
saves messages in your dead.letter file if they are interrupted while being composed. The name of your dead.letter file is given by the DEAD variable. Setting nosave disables this automatic save feature. The default is save.

and **nosave**
Normally, when you abort a message with two interrupt characters (usually control-C), mail copies the partial letter to the file dead.letter in your home directory. Setting the binary option nosave prevents this.

can you please help on this

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore you aren't interrupting an interactive session with Ctrl/C so this option won't help you

Comment: Thanks for your response, i got below answer, that works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes I want to debug with dead.letter, I use:

Makefile...

```
 mail:
       mailx -vs $(a) -a $(a) email@web.com; \
       rm dead.letter
```

Command line...

```
make mail a=file.txt
```

verbose output prevents needing to press ENTER after; dead.letter deleted or fails silently; no other options seem to work (e.g. -i -e ...)